# KDE plasma 5 multiple displays, launcher not displayed properly

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde5

When I use three displays, on the main screen (middle), launcher (Alt+Space or Alt+F2) is not displayed properly.

I took screenshot with mobile because when I use built-in screenshot, launcher fades away.

[image]

Basically it shows only half of the launcher. On other screen it is centered and is displayed properly. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably resolution related thing. My monitors had different resolutions. Once I changed them with new monitors that are same, this issue never appeared again.